# Why is A not 1 nilpotent?

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

I am trying to read a solution for this question:
Given the following matrix in Jordan form,
$$ A= 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    J_5(0) & \\
       & J_6(0)
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
We are asked to find the Jordan form for $A^3$.
Now the solution starts with $A$ is 6 nilpotent, because $A^6 = 0$, thus $A^3$ is 2 nilpotent, because $A^6 = (A^3)^2 = 0$, but I don't understand why is it 2 nilpotent and not 1 nilpotent ?
Is there something I'm missing ? (The rest of the solution I understand)

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think that it should be $1$-nilpotent?

Comment: I haven't literally checked, but couldn't $A^3$ be zero or not ?
Edit: wait, I just payed attention that if $A^3 = 0$ then A would be 3-nilpotent and not 6-nilpotent, am I correct ?